# JSON to java unmarshelling in JAX-RS returning { } in POST

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I am trying to build a JAX-RS rest api that accepts in the POST method a (JSON) UnMarshelled class and at the moment i am only returning the same class (marshelled back as a JSON).

When I return the object i am getting a plain { } in the browser(postman client). I am using the data provided in this [question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365788/unmarshalling-nested-objects-from-json).

Is my understanding correct that the same JSON that i am sending should come back as it is ?, if yes not sure why is only  { } being received or have i completely missed something.

Below is my code :

@Path("/metadata")
public class MetadataResource {

```
//Anil: This is the method that will be called when a post at /metadata comes  
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ObjectA CreateMetadata_JSON(ObjectA metadata) {

    return metadata;

}
```

Class Object A:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "objectA")
public class ObjectA {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String propertyOne;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String propertyTwo;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ObjectB objectB;
}
```

and Class Object B:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "objectB")
public class ObjectB {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String propertyA;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected boolean propertyB;
}
```

The json object being sent is :

```
{ 
  "objectA" : 
  { 
    "propertyOne" : "some val", 
    "propertyTwo" : "some other val",
    "objectB" : 
    {
      "propertyA" : "some val",
      "propertyB" : "true" 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the root object wrapper

```
{ 
  "objectA" : 
  
}
```

Generally the expected JSON object is everything you have, *excluding* the above root value wrapper. If there is a requirement to use the JSON exactly how you have it, then the JSON provider needs to be configured to *un*-wrap the root value. If you don't, then the provider doesn't recognize any properties in the JSON, and you are left with an object with a bunch of nulls. So when you serialize the same object, the provider ignores the null, and you are left with an empty JSON object `{ }`.

So the simple solution is to just use

```
{ 
  "propertyOne" : "some val", 
  "propertyTwo" : "some other val",
  "objectB" : 
  {
    "propertyA" : "some val",
    "propertyB" : "true" 
  }
}
```

If you require the root value wrapper, then I would need to know what JSON provider you are using, before I can try and help with how you can configure it to unwrap the root value.

---

#### UPDATE

For MOXy, if you want to configure it to wrap/unwrap the root value, you can `setIncludeRoot` to true, in the `MoxyJsonConfig`. You will need to provide a `ContextResolver` for it to be discovered.

```
@Provider
public class MoxyConfigResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {
    
    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;
    
    public MoxyConfigResolver() {
        config = new MoxyJsonConfig();
        config.setIncludeRoot(true);
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return config;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet , that did do the trick and thanks for the explaination, just for understanding if i have to unwrap the root as well how would i go about it? i assume Jackson ?, I am using curreny `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: I don't think that is a JSON provider. It is a standalone serialize. I don't think that is what's being used. Do you have anything else? If not maybe the server already has it, and that is what's being used. What server are you  using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you have some other dependency, and don't realize it is the provider. What you have in the comment is for sure not the provider. You can completely get rid of it if you're not using it.

Comment: sorry i am new to json and jax-rs part so i guess i just uncommented this from my archtype project `<artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>` , so moxy is this my dependency thas the json provider?